# Why don't email clients use modern rendering engines?

Tags: html, html-email, email-client, blink

It's 2017 and we are still stuck with HTML tables to create rich emails. Why? It seems reasonable to leverage the hard work behind the modern browser engines (ie. blink), when all you want is to render an HTML document properly.

Comment: Google opened its doors to using stylesheets, divs etc. so no more inline css or tables; did you not know about it? so you'd be good with that.

Comment: Because Outlook is ruled by Microsoft bureaucracy and a historical problem with security flaws in IE. Not everybody uses Outlook, but enough people do. It's the same reason we had to cope with writing code that worked on IE7 for so long.

Comment: I found this while searching for information on html in email. Are there any good guides for it? like metrics on which clients we should care about and how to make html for them, etc?

Comment: @ChrisRollins Yes, here are some [stats on email clients](https://emailclientmarketshare.com/) and [here is a mostly-up-to-date guide on CSS support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) in email clients.

Answer (score 19):

Update: **Since this question was closed and my answer resembles a blog post, I [published an updated version on Medium](https://medium.com/email-design/why-dont-email-clients-use-modern-rendering-engines-1971a0e0fda4#.4vyn695h3)**.

---

Email clients use rendering engines appropriate for **displaying emails**. This is not always in step with displaying web pages.

Only a small % of email users care about HTML/CSS support. Think email marketers and developers. The vast majority of email users simply want a simple, secure way of sending and receiving rich text messages with other people. That’s what email clients are designed for.

Even more advanced users don’t often cite good HTML/CSS support as a top concern. Recent innovations give us a little insight as to what folks are frustrated with regarding email clients: help managing incoming messages, more security, less SPAM, and overall ease of use.

[image]

No one cares if it takes developers a long time to use `<tables>` and inline CSS to create an email. When it comes to changing how emails are rendered… “If it’s not broke, why fix it?” When email clients actually *do* update rendering, it’s rarely news outside of the tech community. Few people care.

Consider **Desktop Outlook**, which typically comes bundled with programs like Word and Powerpoint. All these programs have a similar interface and display output. If you can author a Word document, there’s almost no learning curve in writing an email in Outlook. That’s huge for a lot of people. In all likelihood, Outlook’s rendering engine wasn’t chosen based on it’s ability to render an HTML document properly, yet the product is still considered a success. Because desktop Outlook and doesn’t get automatic updates, old versions (that we have to code for) tend to hang around.

Fun fact: Outlook 2000-2003 rendered email using whatever version of Internet Explorer was installed locally the computer to render email (usually Internet Explorer 6).

**Gmail** is another example. While Gmail has pretty good HTML/CSS support, it didn’t support external CSS files until late 2016. Gmail (unofficially) cited security as one of the reasons. I don’t know what keeps the Gmail team up at night, but I bet it’s not how email developers can’t optimize their email layouts. I bet it’s security. And so that’s where the gmail dev work gets focused.

Overall email clients do their job relatively well. Since HTML/CSS support matters to so few people, changing it is likely not often a priority for product teams that make email clients.

---

**However, things are trending in the right direction.** Gmail and Yahoo! app began supporting media queries in most of their products. Outlook on iOS got a huge facelift including good markup support. New email clients that crop up (Mailbox, Nylus. Polymail) generally have good HTML/CSS support compared to the web. Rarely does support go backwards. The *majority* of clients based on [market share](https://emailclientmarketshare.com/) use “modern rendering engines”.

[image]

Additionally we can always reference our own email analytics. Don’t have many Outlook subscribers? Then code an email using `<div>`s. Don’t need to support *every* mobile client? Then use `media-queries`.

Comment: Good summary. A couple of points: The reason Outlook uses Word's HTML engine instead of IE is actually due to a EU decisions preventing MS from bundling IE with Windows, so MS had to use an alternate rendering engine. Why didn't they keep Word's HTML rendering up to standards? Nobody really cared. However, last year Litmus announced a partnership with MS to advise them on how to bring Outlook into this century. It will be a while before we see anything from this, if at all.

Comment: I was always wondering why it happened that some Outlooks (including the new ones) use Word's rendering engine. I am actually writing a tutorial series about coding HTML emails. May I quote you in the latest post? Also, can you link me some documentation about this decision? I would appreciate it very much. :)

Comment: _Only a small % of email users care about HTML/CSS support._ this is the worst possible explanation without any evidence. They probably don't care because their emails look good because of the tons of workarounds that make them look good. I guess everyone cares about html/css support. Why would anyone want their emails to look like garbage? :-|

Comment: Interesting chat with an outlook's product manager: https://litmus.com/microsoft-partnership

Comment: @MauriciAbad I'm afraid this announcement is several years old. While the intention seemed good, I don't think much actually came out of this partnership. Fingers crossed.